Cohen–Sutherland algorithm
in Cohen–Sutherland algorithm if p1 is in bottom and p2 is in right then the logical and operation between
right=0001, bottom=0100 is 0000 which says the line is inside the clip window when its actually not view this image(1)
its fine if the points where like this view this image(2)
what about the above case it's saying its inside but its completely outside

0 doesn't indicate that the line is inside the clip window.  it indicates that it might be.  You have to clip against one of the relevant boundaries and then retry.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
